# Computing the residues of $\frac{\tan z}{z^2-\pi\frac{z}{4}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> Compute the residues of $$\frac{\tan z}{z^2-\pi\frac{z}{4}}$$

I thought of the following singular points:

$z_k=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi\:\:k\in\mathbb{Z}$ which is a pole of order I cannot determine.

$z=\frac{\pi}{4}$ which is a pole of order 1.

I wonder if $z=\infty$ is a singular point however I am not seeing how to compute $\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{\tan z}{z^2-\pi\frac{z}{4}}$.

However in the book solution the answer was:

$\operatorname{res}_{z=\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\tan z}{z^2-\pi\frac{z}{4}}=\frac{4}{\pi}$

**Questions:**

Why is the solution ruling out $z_k=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi\:\:k\in\mathbb{Z}$?
Is $z=\infty$ a singular point?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Either the book answer is incomplete or you have missed something in the problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the limit $\lim_{z\to\infty}\dfrac{\tan z}{z^2-z\frac\pi4}$ doesn't exist.

And indeed that function has a simple pole at every point of the form $\dfrac\pi2+k\pi$. So, the answer from your textbook is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How did you determine the order of the pole?

Comment: Your function is equal to $\frac{\sin(z)}{\left(z^2-z\frac\pi4\right)\cos(z)}$. At each of the points that I mentioned, the numerator is different from $0$ and the denominator has a simple zero. Therefore, your function has a simple pole.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not know what is a simple zero. I am not seeing how you determined the order of the pole.

Comment: A function $g$ has a simple zero at $z_0$ if $g(z_0)=0$ and $g'(z_0)\neq0$. And if $f(z_0)\neq0$, then $\frac fg$ has then a simple pole at $z_0$, since, near $z_0$,\begin{align}\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}&=\frac{a_0+a_1(z-z_0)+a_2(z-z_0)^2+\cdots}{b_1(z-z_0)+b_2(z-z_0)^2+\cdots}\\&=\frac1{z-z_0}\times\frac{a_0+a_1(z-z_0)+a_2(z-z_0)^2+\cdots}{b_1+b_2(z-z_0)+\cdots}\end{align}and $a_0,b_1\neq0$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can write $f(z)=g(z)/(z-π/4)$ where $g(z)=tan z / z $.
As $g(π/ 4)$ not zero 0 and analytic there, $π/4$ is pole of order 1. So residue is simply $ g(π /4)=4/ π$

Comment: The question was not about the residue at $ z = \pi/4$.

Comment: Oops............